# How do I use a UUID in a @MultipartForm Pojo?

Tags: rest, multipartform-data, resteasy, quarkus

I would like to transfer a **UUID in my DTO** to my resource method.

My method:

```
    @POST
    @Path(("/upload"))
    @Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response sendMultipartData(@MultipartForm MultipartBodyRequestDto data) {
      // Do stuff [...]
        return Response.ok().entity(responseDto).build();
    }
```

My DTO:

```
public class MultipartBodyRequestDto {

    // Other properties [...]

    @NotNull
    @FormParam("file")
    @PartType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
    public InputStream file;

    @NotNull
    @FormParam("id")
    @PartType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN) // <-- What do I have to select here ?
    public UUID id;
}
```

I am getting this error:

> "RESTEASY007545: Unable to find a MessageBodyReader for media type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8 and class type java.util.UUID"

**When switching to String and @PartType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN), it works**, but I have to convert the id myself.

Resteasy should be able to convert it, **after all I am using UUIDs** in other endpoints like this:

```
@GET
@Path("/{id}")
public Response get(@PathParam("id") @NotNull UUID id) {
   // Do stuff [...]
}
```

Do I have to implement a specific **MessageBodyReader** ?

Comment: Is there a reason the UUID would be represented in XML? That seems odd to me.

Comment: There is not. It was a test, I found this example where they used XML for a custom Object: https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/4.5.6.Final/userguide/html/Multipart.html#multipartform_annotation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to provide a `MessageBodyReader<UUID>` which knows how to read the data. Something like the following:

```java
@Provider
public class UuidMessageBodyReader implements MessageBodyReader<UUID> {
    @Override
    public boolean isReadable(final Class<?> type, final Type genericType, final Annotation[] annotations, final MediaType mediaType) {
        return type.isAssignableFrom(UUID.class);
    }

    @Override
    public UUID readFrom(final Class<UUID> type, final Type genericType, final Annotation[] annotations, final MediaType mediaType, final MultivaluedMap<String, String> httpHeaders, final InputStream entityStream) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
        try (ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
            final byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
            int len;
            while ((len = entityStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                out.write(buffer, 0, len);
            }
            return UUID.fromString(out.toString(resolve(mediaType)));
        } finally {
            entityStream.close();
        }
    }

    private String resolve(final MediaType mediaType) {
        if (mediaType != null) {
            final String charset = mediaType.getParameters().get("charset");
            if (charset != null) {
                return charset;
            }
        }
        return "UTF-8";
    }
}
```

Please note this is just a quick example and there is probably a more efficient way of doing this.

The reason it works on your other endpoint is it will just return the `UUID.toString()`. However, there is no default way to read the type as there is not `UUID.valueOf()` method.

Comment: Thank you, I will try that. But what MediaType do I have to specify inside @PartType ?

Comment: It was @PartType(MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM). Thanks.